# Python - How to differentiate SMOTE resampling from original data

Tags: python, machine-learning, oversampling, smote

I over sampled my data using SMOTE like so:

```
>>> from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
>>> X_resampled, y_resampled = SMOTE().fit_resample(X, y)
```

So now `X_resampled, y_resampled` are larger than the original data set.
How can I tell apart the original data from the synthetic samples?

Comment: I rolled back your original question title.  The other one could be misinterpreted and does not relate to your current question at all.

Comment: OK, but why not? X,y are numpy arrays and the X_resampled, y_resampled are numpy arrays containing the original X,y. Comparing the differences between them will solve my issue.

Comment: y_resampled_indicator = [ str(y_resampled[index]) if point in X else (str(y_resampled[index]) + '- synthetic') for index, point in enumerate(X_resampled)].
I was looking for the same anwser. I figured it out by using list comprehension using numpy arrays. It works. Maybe (/probably) not the best way to do it so if you have figured it out with a more 'numpy' way of doing it, I would be interested by the answer ;)